# How to remove a certain time period in zoo format

Tags: r, time-series, zoo, lubridate

I have a time-series data in `zoo` format and another 2 variables data frame in `POSIXct` format recorded the 7 pairs of staring and ending time which represent the time ranges that should be removed . The figure below illustrated the questions graphically. The highlighted regions are the region I have already identified and are expected to be removed.

I know that `window` function can be used to extract these regions, but is there an elegant way to simply remove the data in this region?

Put it simple, any way to delete several periods in a time-series like using the minus (-) sign to remove columns or rows in data frame?

[image: Illustration]

**Supplementary**

The identified period is in a data frame as shown below (in `POSIXct` format)

The time series data is in standard zoo format

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a small example (simulated data)?

Comment: See [mcve] for how to provide a reproducible example.  In this case I have provided one in my answer.

Comment: Many thanks @G.Grothendieck, I'll take a look and follow the instructions in the future.

Answer (score 3):

In short, no.

Recall that `POSIXct` really stores its information as a `double`. Your desired use of the `-` operator, similar to what we do for vector *indices* aims really at *integer* indices where perfect equality can be tested for.

Here you only have inequalities.  So you may want something like this (where I make up date as you did not provided anything reproducible):

```
R> set.seed(42)
R> N <- 1000
R> Z <- zoo( cumsum(rnorm(N)), order.by=Sys.time() + seq(0,by=3*60*60,length=N))
R> summary(Z)
     Index                              Z         
 Min.   :2016-09-19 06:36:25.31   Min.   :-49.91  
 1st Qu.:2016-10-20 11:51:25.31   1st Qu.:-27.43  
 Median :2016-11-20 16:06:25.31   Median :-10.71  
 Mean   :2016-11-20 16:06:25.31   Mean   :-15.89  
 3rd Qu.:2016-12-21 21:21:25.31   3rd Qu.: -6.30  
 Max.   :2017-01-22 02:36:25.31   Max.   :  9.06
```

Now that we have some data, let's just use index logic to exclude a given period -- which we delimit via `ISOdatetime`:

```
R> newZ <- Z[ ! (index(Z) >= ISOdatetime(2016,11,1,0,0,0) \
               & index(Z) <= ISOdatetime(2016,11,30,23,59,59)), ]
R>
```

We can look at the data, and will see that it excluded the desired period as we had aimed for:

```
R> summary(newZ)
     Index                             newZ       
 Min.   :2016-09-19 06:36:25.31   Min.   :-49.91  
 1st Qu.:2016-10-12 23:06:25.31   1st Qu.:-33.73  
 Median :2016-12-05 17:36:25.31   Median :-12.65  
 Mean   :2016-11-22 03:49:42.16   Mean   :-17.74  
 3rd Qu.:2016-12-29 10:06:25.31   3rd Qu.: -5.56  
 Max.   :2017-01-22 02:36:25.31   Max.   :  9.06  
R> table( as.POSIXlt(index(newZ))$mon )   # no November as expected

  0   8   9  11 
169  94 248 248 
R>
```

You may want to look at [xts](https://cran.r-project.org/package=xts) indexing though.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the start and end indices of the subsets known, you can use the following, for each of the subsets, assuming x is the data in zoo format:

```
x[start.index:end.index] <- NA
na.omit(x)
```

In order to find index of the POSIXct time in the data in zoo format, you can use something like the following:

```
x
2012-04-09 05:03:00 2012-04-09 05:04:00 2012-04-09 05:05:39 2012-04-09 05:09:00 2012-04-09 05:10:00 
                  2                   4                 3                   6                   1 

which(index(x) >= '2012-04-09 05:09:00' & index(x) <= '2012-04-09 05:10:00')
4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by sandipan's answer, I wrote a small function as below which solved the problem. Where dat is a time-series in `zoo` and hl.period is the 2 variables data frame in `POSIXct` format as shown in the question. However, I believe there should be a more elegant way to solve this problem.

Also thanks for Dirk's contribution. Your approach looks promising. But as I'm new to time-series analysis, I need to do some homework to understand your approach.

```
del_periods<-function(dat,hl.period)
{
   for (i in 1:nrow(hl.period))
   {
       window(dat,start=hl.period[i,1],end=hl.period[i,2])<-NA
       dat<-na.omit(dat)
   }
  return(dat)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two possible one-liners.  Perhaps not as simple as desired but they are short and the second one does use minus.

**1) findInterval** zoo indexes can be logical so this code works using  logical condition with `findInterval` where `z` is the input POSIXct zoo series., `st` is POSIXct vector of starts and `en` is a corresponding POSIXct vector of ends.  The code below forms `c(st[1], en[1] + .001, st[2], en[2] + .001, ...)` so that the even numbered intervals represent ranges to be kept and odd to be excluded.  This does assume that the intervals are ordered and nonoverlapping so that `st[1] < en[1] < st[2] < en[2] < ...` That does appear to be the case in the question.

```
z[ findInterval(index(z), c(rbind(st, en + .001))) %% 2 == 0 ]
```

Note that if the length of `st` and `en` are each 1 then it simplifies to:

```
z[ findInterval(index(z), c(st, en + .001)) != 1 ]
```

**2) match** If the `st` and `en` values are among the `index(z)` values we could alternately use `match`.  for example, this would be the case with the starts and ends shown in the question if `z` were an hourly series.  This takes advantage of the fact that `z[-(3:4)]` works to exclude elements 3 and 4, say, from the zoo series `z`.  The code below transforms the POSIXct values to indexes among 1, 2, 3, ..., length(z) and exludes using minus.

```
z[ - unlist(Map(seq, match(st, index(z)), match(en, index(z)))) ]
```

Note that if the length of `st` and `en` are each 1 then it simplifies to just:

```
z[ - seq(match(st, index(z)), match(en, index(z)) ]
```

**Example of (2)**

For example, try it with these inputs:

```
library(zoo)

tt <- seq(as.POSIXct("2011-01-01 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2011-01-04 23:00:00"), by="hour")
z <- zoo(seq_along(tt), tt)

st <- as.POSIXct(c("2011-01-02 13:00:00", "2011-01-04 15:00:00"))
en <- as.POSIXct(c("2011-01-02 14:00:00", "2011-01-04 17:00:00"))
```

Now we can run this.

```
z0 <- z[ - unlist(Map(seq, match(st, index(z)), match(en, index(z)))) ]
plot(z0, type = "p", pch = 20)
```

Note the two excluded regions in the graph below.

[image: screenshot]